# Right way to convert char * number to int32_t

Tags: c, linux, type-conversion

I want to convert number from char * format to 32 bit integer int32_t, but strtol() returns long.

I don't know length of long on my machine. It could be 32 or 64 bit or something else in the future.

What is the correct and bulletproof way to convert string to 32 bit integer int32_t? Or to convert long to int32_t.

Is comparison to _MAX and _MIN constants the only and most simple way?

Comment: What's wrong with `sprintf("%i", ...)`? Doesn't it automatically handle 32/64-bit systems properly?

Comment: Polynomial, problem is that %i does not correspond to int32_t. Anyway, the correct answer is below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `sscanf` with one of the format specifier macros from `<inttypes.h>`, e.g. `SCNd32` or `SCNi32`:

```
int32_t i;
sscanf(str, "%"SCNd32, &i);
```

These are available since C99.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about that. You can find a list in http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=inttypes.html#SCNd8.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *buf;
long val;
....
if (1 == sscanf(buf, "%ld", &val) )
{
   // success!
   // now we have the data in a long, can do some boundary checking and then put it in an int32_t.
}
...
```